# Can I tokenize a string using t-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, tokenize

I was wondering if I have SQL Server 2008 table that was created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id INT PRIMARY KEY, 
                  dvt NVARCHAR(32), 
                  d0 TINYINT, 
                  d1 TINYINT, 
                  d2 TINYINT);
INSERT INTO tbl (id, dvt, d0, d1, d2) 
 VALUES(1, '1', NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO tbl (id, dvt, d0, d1, d2) 
 VALUES(2, '', NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO tbl (id, dvt, d0, d1, d2) 
 VALUES(3, '2,5', NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO tbl (id, dvt, d0, d1, d2) 
 VALUES(4, '13, 34, 45, 5', NULL, NULL, NULL);
INSERT INTO tbl (id, dvt, d0, d1, d2) 
 VALUES(5, '1,8, 10', NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

I need to take the string from the 'dvt' column and split it into 'd0', 'd1' and 'd2' columns. The 'dvt' value can be separated by commas.

I can do this using C# and a tokenization function but I was wondering if it's possible to do the same using SQL?

Columns BEFORE:

```
1, "1",             NULL, NULL, NULL
2, "",              NULL, NULL, NULL
3, "2,5",           NULL, NULL, NULL
4, "13, 34, 45, 5", NULL, NULL, NULL
5, "1,8, 10",       NULL, NULL, NULL
```

Columns AFTER:

```
1, "1",             1,    NULL, NULL
2, "",              NULL, NULL, NULL
3, "2,5",           2,    5,    NULL
4, "13, 34, 45, 5", 13,   34,   45  -- 5 is discarded
5, "1,8, 10",       1,    8,    10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with this type of code is re-use of calculations.

SQL Server is good at caching results *(If you **type** the exact same `CHARINDEX()` caluculation 5 times, it only calculates once and re-uses that result 4 times)*.

That's little consolation for the poor coder who has to type or maintain that code though.

SQL Server 2005 onward has `CROSS APPLY` that does help somewhat.  The logic is repeated, but the results can be referenced repeatedly, rather that the calculation typed repeatedly.

```
SELECT
  *,
  SUBSTRING(dvt, 1,            ISNULL(comma1.pos-1, LEN(dvt))           ) AS item1,
  SUBSTRING(dvt, comma1.pos+1, ISNULL(comma2.pos-1, LEN(dvt))-comma1.pos) AS item2,
  SUBSTRING(dvt, comma2.pos+1, ISNULL(comma3.pos-1, LEN(dvt))-comma2.pos) AS item3
FROM
(
  SELECT 'ab,c,def,hij' AS dvt
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'xyz,abc'      AS dvt
)
  AS data
OUTER APPLY
  (SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', data.dvt, 1           ), 0) AS pos                     )  AS comma1
OUTER APPLY
  (SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', data.dvt, comma1.pos+1), 0) AS pos WHERE comma1.pos > 0)  AS comma2
OUTER APPLY
  (SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', data.dvt, comma2.pos+1), 0) AS pos WHERE comma2.pos > 0)  AS comma3
OUTER APPLY
  (SELECT NULLIF(CHARINDEX(',', data.dvt, comma3.pos+1), 0) AS pos WHERE comma3.pos > 0)  AS comma4
```

Another option is to simply write a *table valued user defined function* that does this (even when the result of the function is always one row).  Then you simply `CROSS APPLY` that function.

Comment: Thanks for the sample. I did some adjusting for my situation. It turned out pretty bulky, and also had to get rid of TINYINT in favor of SMALLINT. Please take a look: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c84703/1

Comment: @ahmd0 - Sorry, I can't get to SQLFiddle from this corporate network. If you add the code to your question I can have a look at it for you. Another generalised option would be to to write a table valued function that takes a single string parameter and returns one row with two fields (`head, tail`) where `head` is everything before the first comma and `tail` is everything after the first comma. *(If no comma, head = the whole input parameter, tail = null)*. You can then cross apply that three times to get your first three values.

Comment: @Dems - just curious, but what is preventing your access to SQL Fiddle on your corporate network?  In the past I've talked with an Internet whitelist outfit, and have gotten "approved" for their lists; is that what you're experiencing? I would be happy to chat with whatever group is managing your corporate whitelist filter to try to get that resolved (assuming that's what's going on).

Comment: @JakeFeasel - Not sure of the details.  Using IE6 on XP it loads the page then what I presume is AJAX tries to populate the two pains, but it gets stuck.  And I can't install another browser.

Comment: @Dems - gah! IE6, my condolences.  Yes it definitely doesn't work with that old of a browser.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
 ;WITH Vals AS (
         SELECT id,
                dvt,
                CAST('<r>'+REPLACE(dvt,',','</r><r>')+'</r>' AS XML).query('/r[1]').value('.','varchar(max)') d1,
                CAST('<r>'+REPLACE(dvt,',','</r><r>')+'</r>' AS XML).query('/r[2]').value('.','varchar(max)') d2,
                CAST('<r>'+REPLACE(dvt,',','</r><r>')+'</r>' AS XML).query('/r[3]').value('.','varchar(max)') d3
         FROM   tbl
)
SELECT  id,
        dvt,
        CASE WHEN d1 = '' THEN NULL ELSE d1 END d1,
        CASE WHEN d2 = '' THEN NULL ELSE d2 END d2,
        CASE WHEN d3 = '' THEN NULL ELSE d3 END d3
FROM    Vals
```

Comment: Wow, interesting. One thing though, I was trying it in SQLFiddle and got this: The query has been canceled because the estimated cost of this query (575) exceeds the configured threshold of 200. Any idea what that means?

Comment: Not realy, no. I ran this on sql server 2008. Might mean that the query will be too intensive?

Comment: Well, thanks anyway! I need to study it -- to see what it does before I mark it.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible.

You could do it with some repetitive calls to `CHARINDEX` and checking for nulls but it may be better and clearer to write a `FUNCTION` to split the string.

Answer (score -2):

I needed String tokenizer for Sybase; separation by 1 or more spaces in name data
Name date clean and has no commas or other special characters

```
declare @test varchar(60)
select @test=str_replace(lower(rtrim('Jayanta  Narayan     Choudhuri'))," ",",")
exec sp_splitwords @test
```

This is based on a neat hint by Kenny Lucas from http://www.sql9.com/?id=102

```
drop proc sp_splitwords
go
create proc sp_splitwords(@instr varchar(80)) as
begin
  declare @pos  int, 
          @word varchar(80), 
          @list varchar(81)

  create table #words(word varchar(80))    
  select @list = @instr + ','    
  set @pos = patindex('%,,%',@list)
  while @pos > 0
  begin
    select @list = str_replace(@list,',,',',')    
    set @pos = patindex('%,,%',@list)
  end


  set @pos = patindex('%,%',@list)

  while @pos > 0
  begin    
    set @word = substring(@list, 1,@pos-1)            
    set @list = substring(@list, @pos+1,len(@list)-@pos)    
    if NOT( @word is null OR LEN(@word) = 0 )
      insert into #words (word) values (@word)    
    set @pos = patindex('%,%',@list)
  end

  select * from #words
  order by len(word) desc

  drop table #words
end
```

I could port Metaphone SQL Function to Sybase
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=125724

Sybase allows recursion in functions from a beautiful workaround
http://www.sypron.nl/quiz2008a.html#jan08

```
CREATE FUNCTION Metaphone2 (@str VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(25) AS
BEGIN
  RETURN @str 
END

DROP FUNCTION Metaphone2
GO
CREATE FUNCTION Metaphone2 (@str VARCHAR(100))
RETURNS VARCHAR(25) AS
BEGIN
  RETURN dbo.Metaphone(@str)
END
```

Changed 1 line of Function pasted from http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=125724

Combination of metaphone and string tokenizer means I can fuzzy search names 
first middle and surname and rotations thereof

Comment: You did see the question is tagged with sql-server? There are a view differences.