# How to Convert Semi colon Separated Values into Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on a integration project where I am receiving three string parameters 
ItemCode
ItemName
Amount

and values will be in this format

**ItemCod Parameter values**
T1;T2;T3;

**ItemName Parameter values**
Pencil Box;Eraser;Mouse Pad;

**Amount Paramter values**
1900;2000;8900;

Now I would like to have a procedure in which i would receive these parameters and the query will convert this as column and records. I am not a SQLServer guy and I did the something similar in Oracle for sending. But this one is receiving in semi colon seperated and convert into columns and rows. I apologize for poor quality posting. here is the Oracle attempt.

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE PROC_SENDREQDETAILS 
(
  P_REQ_NUMBER VARCHAR2  
, P_ATTRIBUTE1 VARCHAR2
, P_LOCATION_NAME VARCHAR2
, P_ITEM_ID VARCHAR2  
, P_QTY VARCHAR2
, P_NEED_BY_DATE VARCHAR2
, P_ATTRIBUTE3 VARCHAR2
) IS
BEGIN

INSERT INTO PO_REQUISITIONS_STAGING(req_number_segment1, attribute1, location_name, item_id, quantity, need_by_date, attribute3)
 select  regexp_substr(request_number,'[^;]+',1,level),
         regexp_substr(attribute1,'[^;]+',1,level),
         regexp_substr(location_name,'[^;]+',1,level),
         regexp_substr(item_id,'[^;]+',1,level),
         regexp_substr(quantity,'[^;]+',1,level),
         regexp_substr(need_by_date,'[^;]+',1,level),
         regexp_substr(attribute3,'[^;]+',1,level)
  from  (
      select P_REQ_NUMBER request_number, P_ATTRIBUTE1 attribute1, P_LOCATION_NAME location_name, P_ITEM_ID item_id, P_QTY quantity, P_NEED_BY_DATE need_by_date, P_ATTRIBUTE3 attribute3
      from dual
      )
  connect by regexp_substr(request_number,'[^;]+',1,level) is not null;
end;
--END PROC_SENDREQDETAILS;
```

Comment: Please edit your post to include your attempt at a solution. Thank you.

Comment: *Very low quality:* What have you tried? Where is your code?

Comment: ok I just updated my question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly related to this: [Can I tokenize a string using t-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861181/can-i-tokenize-a-string-using-t-sql)

You can use XML query to tokenise the values:

```
INSERT INTO t
(cod, name)
VALUES
('T1;T2;',
 'Pencil Box;Eraser;');

---------------------------
|COD   |NAME              |
|T1;T2;|Pencil Box;Eraser;|
---------------------------

INSERT t2
SELECT
  CAST('<r>'+REPLACE(cod,';','</r><r>')+'</r>' AS XML).query('/r[1]').value('.','varchar(256)') cod,
  CAST('<r>'+REPLACE(name,';','</r><r>')+'</r>' AS XML).query('/r[1]').value('.','varchar(256)') name
FROM t;

INSERT t2
SELECT
  CAST('<r>'+REPLACE(cod,';','</r><r>')+'</r>' AS XML).query('/r[2]').value('.','varchar(256)') cod,
  CAST('<r>'+REPLACE(name,';','</r><r>')+'</r>' AS XML).query('/r[2]').value('.','varchar(256)') name
FROM t;

----------------
|COD|NAME      |
|T1 |Pencil Box|
|T2 |Eraser    |
----------------
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/258a5/1

Comment: Cong superbbbbbbbbb...you rock man :) just need one thing in your code  which is I don't want to insert the values into table..just want to get the output using SELECT only..no INSERT INTO :) can i have one query which will make columns and generate output as multiple records?

Comment: I am not marking this as answer as according to this solution the number of records are not defined and it can be more then 2 so as per the solution proposed its a limited solution.